# Best practice for Models to Views

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have views that are not using every property on my view.  For example, the userId property doesn't need to be shown on the view.  Right now I am storing thew value in a hidden field.  is there a standard or more secure way to keep my views intact such as session or something else in MVC without exposing all the data of my model on view either through a field or hidden field?

Seems like a basic question where this a webforms I would probably just store it in a session, But i am curious to know if MVC provides different support or there is best practice way I have over looked.

**EDIT**
Ok what i left out is that.  When I do not store the UserId field either in readonly editable value or hidden field when form submits the model back to the controller, the UserId is null.

What I am asking how are other preventing this?  what is the normal, best practice of hidding the user Id (or any property) that is not needed to show?

Comment: Yes you can remove those fields (for which you are not taking any value from user) from your view. That is simple and standard. If you face any problem after removing that could be helped out.

Comment: The problem when i dont have them or represent the values in hidden fields when the model gets submitted back to the controller, the fields i didnt store in hidden fields or editable fields are returned null

Comment: Yes.. I had that problem too.. You could set a value to that null field when u get view in controller. As u are not taking it from user.. so you would have it on the server side which is easily accessible in controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with having the UserId property on the client being sent on each request. It is on the server that you should implement authorization logic which checks whether this user id that comes from the browser actually belongs to the currently authenticated user. No need to be using any ASP.NET Sessions for that.

If you are using [`Forms Authentication`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647070.aspx) to track the currently authenticated user, then you could always securely retrieve this user.

Comment: Yes i am using Forms Auth.  Maybe the question really.  this is my first fully blown out tiered(layered) MVC application.  it is geared to support MVC web clients and mobile clients with webApi.  So execuse my ignorance.  Should I not be using the ORM Model all the way, but have subsets of each ORM Model according to what needs to get manipulated by the user.  That seems like a lot of extra work, which still leaves me in the same place of having  to manually tell the save process which field should updated

Comment: I always write view models for each particular view. A view model could be composed of multiple domain models.

Comment: what about when u update a table that has 10 fields and the model only has gave the user 3 to update.  does that mean u get the entity update the changed fields mark them modified and save.  so all the non modified fields dont get changed?

Comment: ok thanks.  That clears up a lot.  Let me ask this, you dont find it a lot to maintain a bunch of subset of models?